# How can a WCF service be bound to a static port?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

This could be a very trivial question to many, but I haven't got a solution as to how I can make my WCF service run on a static port on Visual Studio development server so that my client can directly add the service reference and consume it. 
I'm using .net 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 professional edition where the Project properties window does not have the option to disable dynamic port usage.
Any ideas as to how I can make it happen will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See [How to: Specify a Port for the Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx) for a few ways.

Comment: I did try all the viable options but none of them work for VS 2013.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install IIS on your development workstation and use that to host your WCF service?

Comment: I could get around it it by using VS 2010 which is not a solution per se, but I managed to keep the port static by changing the port allocation property for WCF service. Still does not answer why that could not happen in VS 2013.

Comment: @1.618 I was just experimenting with the visual studio development server assuming that my target website supports only older versions of IIS.